# Facebook apprequest (notification) is it possible?

Tags: facebook, notifications, app-id

I want to make an app with apprequest sending to some friends of that user. 
how to send notification to 20 friend who not run app, with some message.
How can with javascript get 20 userids of friends and automatically send notification to start app, or some message?

Comment: answered May 20 '11 :/ now is 2014...

Comment: It's still not possible to send user to user requests without using the requests dialog